# How to find the ID number of a value?

Tags: r, find, uniqueidentifier

I am currently working with a dataset with 551 observation and 141 variables. Normally there are some mistakes done by the data entry operators and I am now screening and correcting those. But the problem is the ID number and the row number of the dataset is not similar/corresponding. And I can only bring the row number where the problematic data lies in. It is taking more time of mine to find the ID number as they do not correspond. Is there any way to get the ID number of the problematic data within one command?

Suppose, the row number of the B345 ID, is #1. For B346 ID the row is #2.

My dataset is presented like this-

```
ID    S1    S2    S3    I30    I31    I34  
B345  12    23    3     2      1      4
B346  15    4     4     3      2      4
```

I am using the following command in my original dataset and got the following results. Row number 351 and 500 but actually their ID number is B456 and B643.

```
which (x$I30 ==0)
[1] 351 500
```

I am expecting to get the ID number within 1 command. It will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

`x$ID[which(x$I30==0)]`

Comment: It works for my numeric value. What if I had a string variable and the variable name is some area like New York City, Florida etc. ?

Comment: then `x$ID[which(x$I30=="New York City")]` should work

Answer (score 2):

We can just use the logical condition to subset the 'ID'

```
x$ID[x$I30 ==0]
```